# Jenkins parameterized build triggering with no parameters

Tags: angularjs, jenkins

I have an internal website that I am developing for my company in order to trigger builds of our mobile app from a Jenkins job. The website is written in AngularJS and I am using the http module to call Jenkins.

My angular method in my service looks like this:

```
  postBuildRequest : function(platform, project, ticket, environment, username, password, callback)
  {
    var method = 'GET';
    var url = "http://JENKINS_URL/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters";
    var params =
    {
      token: "some_job_token",
      parameter: [{ platform: platform, project: project, ticket: ticket, environment: environment }]
    }
    var headers =
    {
      "Authorization": "Basic " + window.btoa(username + ":" + password)
    }
    var config =
    {
        method: method,
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        params: params
    };

    $http(config).then(
      function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("postBuildRequest Success!! \n" + response.statusText + " with Status Code: " + response.status);
        callback(response);
      },
      function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("postBuildRequest Error :( \n" + response.statusText + " with Status Code: " + response.status);
        callback(response);
      }
    );

  }
```

My Jenkins job has the following parameters setup:

[image]

My build command inside the job looks like this (shell):

```
# Parse the build variant
if [$environment == 'live']; then
    liveorstaging='--live'
elif [$environment == 'staging']; then
    liveorstaging='--staging'
else 
    liveorstaging=''
fi

# Run the config buildandroid script
if ! [ -z $ticket ]; then
    config buildandroid $project -t $ticket $liveorstaging --commit
else 
    config buildandroid $project --live --commit
fi
```

I can trigger the build fine,but it is failing because it doesn't see the parameters.

My console is spitting out:

```
12:44:39 Usage: config buildandroid [OPTIONS] PROJECT
12:44:39 
12:44:39 Error: Missing argument "project".
12:44:39 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
12:44:39 Finished: FAILURE
```

And if I look at the parameters, they are empty:

[image]

So... I am obviously doing something wrong with my HTTP request... any thoughts ?

Comment: your build script contains syntax errors

Comment: does it ? the job can run manually... (it fails eventually because the Python script it calls has an issue... )

Comment: Yes, you are missing whitespace in the environment checks, but even if that was fixed, none of the if conditions will ever be true because you are comparing static strings (`environment` should be `$environment`).

Comment: ah, yes, i had updated the $, caught that, but thanks. im not sure where the whitespace issue is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I fixed it. I realized that i was taking the Wiki page at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build VERY literally and posting all of my parameters as

```
PARAMETER=[{key:value}]
```

where I should have been doing like such:

```
  var params =
    {
      token: token,
      key1: value1,
      key2: value2,
      key3: value3,
      key4: value4
    }
```

So that my url looks like:

```
buildWithParameters?environment=staging&platform=some_platform&project=some_project&ticket=some_ticket&token=eb_some_token
```